# failed to open stream

Tags: php

Separei o código PHP do arquivo `register.php` em diretórios `includes/handlers` com dois arquivos `register-handler.php` e `login-handler.php`, então fiz

```
<?php
    include("handlers/register-handler.php");
    include("handlers/login-handler.php");
?>
```

Apareceu as mensagens:

> Warning: include(includes/handlers/register-handler.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Slotify\register.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'includes/handlers/register-handler.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\Slotify\register.php
>   on line 2

E

> Warning: include(includes/handlers/login-handler.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Slotify\register.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'includes/handlers/login-handler.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\Slotify\register.php
>   on line 3

Versão:

```
php 5.6.25
apache 2.4.23
WAMPSERVER 3.0.6 x64
Windows 7 x64
```

[image: Estrutura]

Comment: Meu deus que vergonha!!!

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está incluindo o arquivo **"handlers/register-handler.php"**, mas a pasta é **handles**, sem o **r**.